# How to enable logging for WebACL in AWS WAF using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

I was going through [AWS WAF Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-waf-webacl.html) documentation and I couldn't see a way to enable logging. I can enable logging by console, however I want to do it by Cloudformation so that it is enabled by default in new stacks.

How do I enable logging in AWS WAF WebACL by Cloudformation.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't a way to do this natively with cloudformation. You'll have to write a custom lambda resource to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported right now. Likely because of this:

> [If you are capturing logs for Amazon CloudFront, create the firehose in US East (N. Virginia)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/trimming-aws-waf-logs-with-amazon-kinesis-firehose-transformations/)

Which means this stack would need to be creating resources in multiple regions.

You can track and vote for the issue on the CloudFormation road-map page [here](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/349)

Answer (score 1):

It's not available at the moment but it is possible to use AWS Config to set up logging as new web ACLs are created.

Answer (score 0):

AWS WAF Security Automations has used lambda to sovle this.

```
   ConfigureAWSWAFLogs:
    Type: 'Custom::ConfigureAWSWAFLogs'
    Condition: HttpFloodProtectionLogParserActivated
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt CustomResource.Arn
      WAFWebACLArn: !GetAtt WebACLStack.Outputs.WAFWebACLArn
      DeliveryStreamArn: !GetAtt FirehoseAthenaStack.Outputs.FirehoseWAFLogsDeliveryStreamArn
```

CustomResource lambda funtion

```
elif event['ResourceType'] == "Custom::ConfigureAWSWAFLogs":
            if 'CREATE' in request_type:
                put_logging_configuration(log, event['ResourceProperties']['WAFWebACLArn'],
                                          event['ResourceProperties']['DeliveryStreamArn'])
```

check it out at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-waf-security-automations

[amazon-waf](/questions/tagged/amazon-waf)[aws-waf-security-automations](/questions/tagged/aws-waf-security-automations)

Answer (score 0):

It's already available. Official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-loggingconfiguration.html)

Related release note for added support (CloudWatch and S3) [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/12/awf-waf-cloudwatch-log-s3-bucket/)

Answer (score 0):

Use
**AWS::WAFv2::LoggingConfiguration**

Refer
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-loggingconfiguration.html